# SQLite database table display format

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created an sqlite database for my android application. I have two text views and an update button which inserts these values in the db. Initially the table colums labels look good since I used the `android:stretchColumns="*"` tag in `<TableLayout>`. But as I make an entry, the values are not displayed under the specific columns!
I want the columns properly formatted. How can this be done? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. Here's my view database code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#cc0000"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="ID"
            android:textColor="#eeddff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Subject Name"
            android:textColor="#eeddff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Assignment Number"
            android:textColor="#eeddff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dataDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#eeddff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: This is not the `database code`, this is your xml layout for the activity! Post the code which is inserting the values in the database and the code of the Adapter.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the sqlite inserting code. The data is being saved successfully. No issues with that. Just that the table does not display the data properly column wise.